# Create java classes from UML diagram

Tags: java, uml

I have to create java classes based on this `UML diagram`.
The problem is that I don't know what is the relationship inside the red shape.
I did all the other relationships between the `A, B, C, D` classes but this one I cannot understand it.

Can anyone give me a hint ?

So far I have :

```
class A extends B

class D extends C

class C 
List<B> bElement;

class D 
List<A> aElement;
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure if it is valid UML?

Comment: It seems to be created with a UML tool. The image here attached is a little modified. So, I'm guessing is a valid one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the lower association inherits from the upper one. Just like the lower classes inherit from the upper ones.

The concept of connector inheritance has only been introduced in a recent UML release (according to @Henriette's answer from 2.0 on). Anyhow, neither the lower association nor its generalization is actually needed since its inherited along with the both generalizations anyway.

Personally I have not found a good use for this concept, but know people that do use it (they work on very high abstraction levels in ontology).

P.S. There's not much to be read about the concept in the specs except for p. 692:

> Generalization arrows between association lines are interchanged as UMLEdges with Generalizations as modelElements, and sources and targets that are UMLEdges with Associations (including AssociationClasses shown as lines) as modelElements.

Comment: So, this means that it's only used for the "diagram beauty" ? Nothing to add to java classes to translate this relationship ?

Comment: In this case it's probably just "part of the lesson" and you can ignore it for an implementation. As said, I'm still seeking for a meaningful application of this concept.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Association inheritance was introduced in UML 2.0 in 2005. Although UML is probably most often used in object-oriented analysis and design, it is aimed at being a general purpose **modeling language**. As such it includes features like multiple inheritance, attribute specialization/refinement and association inheritance that is not necessarily supported in programming languages. However, in ontology languages like OWL 2 these notions are natural to express.

For some other purposes I have done a write-up w.r.t. association inheritance and equivalent UML representations, which I provide here for in case it is helpful to others.

[image: Association inheritance equivalent representations]

With regards to associations and attributes the UML specification defines three closely related notions namely `association specialization`, `subsetting` and `redefinition`. Association specialization is applied at the level of the complete association while subsetting and redefinition
are applied at the level of association ends and attributes.

The meaning of association specialization is similar to that of classes. That is, association `A2` is a specialization of association `A1` in Figure (a). Therefore every link between instances of classes `C3` and `C4` is necessarily a link between instances of classes `C1` and `C2`. However, every link between instances of classes `C1` and `C2` is not necessarily a link between instances of classes `C3` and `C4`.

Due to `C3/C4` specializing `C1/C2` in Figure (a), it follows that all associations between `C1` and `C2` will be inherited by `C3` and `C4`. Moreover, all inherited associations between `C3` and `C4` will necessarily be subsets of the associations between `C1` and `C2`. However, 
Figure (a) goes further than that: not only is the association `A1` inherited by `C3` and `C4`, it also introduce a new association `A2`. Since `A2` is a new association, without the association specialization one will not be able to deduce anything about how `A1` relates to `A2`. Hence, in Figure (a) the purpose of the association inheritance is to introduce a new association `A2` and state how it relates to the existing association `A1`.

In Figure (b) it is stated that `c4 {subsets c2}`. This means that the collection of instances represented by the association end `c4` is a subset of the collection of instances represented by the association end `c2`. The same holds for association ends `c3` and `c1`. Subsetting
is distinguished from association specialization in that subsetting considers set membership only whereas association specialization specializes the characteristics that determine link membership.

Redefinition is used to change the definition of a feature. As an example association end `c4` redefines `c2` in Figure (c). Redefinition is distinguished from association specialization in that redefinition is defined for an association end rather than for the complete association.

Though the original question pertained to association inheritance used in inheritance hierarchies, it may be enlightening to note that association inheritance can also be used in the absence of inheritance hierarchies. In Figure (d) all the woman a man has been divorced from is a subset of the women he has been married to.

[image]

In Figures (a) and (d) the associations are first class citizens of the model. They therefore may be represented by association classes (`A1/A2` and `MarriedTo/DivorceFrom`) with an inheritance relation between the respective association classes, though making use of association specialization may be more succinct in indicating your intention to specialize associations than specialization between association classes.

In summary: The specialization of an association is equivalent to the subsetting of (one of) its ends and redefinition can be treated as a subconcept of subsetting.

Comment: Though I have a gist to what subset/redef can be used, I'm still lost why one needs (a). Doesn't C3/4 inherit the association from C1/2 when you generalize it this way? Or is it just that I weigh connectors differently and make them 2nd class citizens?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ThomasKilian. You make a fair point wrt to connectors as 1st vs 2nd class citizens. I have updated my answer to take into account your comments.

Comment: Thanks very much for that detailed explanation. I can now see a bit clearer. There are more questions, but those would explode this comment section and I'll eventually ask them as new questions instead. I'd upvote your answer more than once if that were possible :-)